# How i can make comboBox for represent connected com ports

Tags: c#, wpf

My program does not display the connected com ports, where is my mistake?

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxComPort" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="100" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="5 3 5 3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

C#

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboBoxComPort.Items.Add(ports);
    }
```

Comment: "_where is my mistake?_" I wager, you don't provide no collection with values for the combobox to display. I see that you attempt to add items/values to the combobox in the SelectionChanged event handler for the combobox. But ask yourself this: How can the selection in the combobox change (and thus the SelectionChanged event handler be called) if the combobox has not items that could be selected to begin with? And why would you want to add items to the combobox when an item in the combobox is being selected; how would doing so make any sense?

Comment: First of all i would seeing in ComboBox all connected com ports with my PC, and when i choose some port, i add it in list.

Comment: When i created program in Windows Forms App, this  method worked

Comment: Read my comment again. "_First of all i would seeing in ComboBox all connected com ports with my PC_". To be able to see the ports in the ComboBox, you need to add them to the combobox first, no?

Comment: "_When i created program in Windows Forms App, this method worked_" No, it wouldn't. If you would have done the equivalent code in WinForms as to what you show here in your question, it would NOT have worked there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `Selection_Changed`-Event for loading..
Use the `Loaded` event for this in your XAML like `Loaded="comboBoxComPort_Loaded"`

And then change the code behind to:

```
    private void comboBoxComPort_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach (string port in ports)
            comboBoxComPort.Items.Add(port);
    }
```